# How do I use Intent for working perfekt in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to get a variable on my Android App from 1 Activite to an other.
Ther for I using Intent but I have a Problem with it and I can´t find any answer for it. When I lauch the programm it say´s me every time 90 no matter waht I do.

MainActivitie

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static final String EXTRA_NUMBER = "com.example.akkuapp.EXTRA_NUMBER";

int level;
public TextView battery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    battery = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textakku);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));



    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Hintergrundservice.class);

    PendingIntent startServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, startServiceIntent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();



    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 5, startServicePendingIntent);

}


public final BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        battery.setText(String.valueOf(level) + '%');

        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, level);
    }
};
```

Backgroundservice

`
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

```
        level = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER,90);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(level), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("Hintergrundprozess", String.valueOf(level));



    return flags;
}



@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

[Pictur MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exjmu.png)

[Pictur Hintergrundprozess (Backgroundservice)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMyoj.png)

Thank you for your Help

Comment: You are already getting the intent in onStartCommand. Fetch the data from that intent. Also, you need to pass the data from the Activity which you are not passing.

Comment: Could you add your code here instead of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems here. You are using `startActivity()` but passing an `Intent` for a `Service` (`HintergrundService`). To start a `Service` you need to call `startService()`.

Also, `getIntentOld()` is a deprecated method of `Intent` and is probably not what you want. You already have the `Intent` as it is passed into `onStartCommand()`. Just use `intent.getIntExtra()`:

```
intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER, 90);
```

---

EDIT: Add more data after seeing more code

You have used `AlarmManager` to schedule the triggering of an `Intent` to start your `Service`. In that `Intent` you have not put any extras. This is the reason that your `Service` doesn't get the "extra".

When your `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered and `onReceive()` is called, you extract the battery level from the incoming `Intent` and add an "extra" with that value back to the same incoming `Intent`. The value doesn't get magically copied into the `Intent` that you passed to `AlarmManager`. You should really find some tutorials and examples and learn more about how all this works.

In general, if your `Service` wants to get the battery level, it can just do this:

```
IntentFilter ifilter =
    new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
```

You don't need to actually register a `BroadcastReceiver`. The battery changed `Intent` is a "sticky" `Intent`, which means that the last one broadcast is held by the Android framework and you can always ask for the last one that was broadcast.

See https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring for more information about monitoring the battery state.

Comment: OK Thank you for your help. I had now write in the MainActivity `intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, level);` and in the service `level = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER,90);`  .But I get only 90 from my Programm no matter waht I do.

Comment: You need to call `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, level)` to add the extra to the `Intent` in `MainActivity`.

Comment: OK. I now added `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, level);` in my `MainActivity`. But it still say 90.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your updated code. Without seeing the code I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: OK. I Update my question and post my Code in the pictures.

Comment: Both links point to screenshots of `HintergrundService`. Please provide the code for `MainActivity`. Generally you should copy/paste the code into your question instead of providing image links.

Comment: Another problem I see is that in `onStartCommand()` you do this: `return flags;`. Why would you do this? You need to return one of the expected values: `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY, START_STICKY, START_NOT_STICKY, or START_REDELIVER_INTENT`. Please refer to the documentation for `Service.onStartCommand()`.

Comment: You really should have a look at a few tutorials/examples of how to do this. There are plenty available on the Internet. You need a guideline otherwise you will spend way too much time on this.

Comment: Hi, over the Day I thinking about the programm and I got an idear. I wrote `level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);` in my service so I don´t need to bring the Batterylevel from 1 Activitie to the Service and save Ressorces. It the complet same Code but it is´t working in the service it´s the same like the Intent I only get my sandart number in this case 0. I watched in the Internet but coden´t a toturial with Batterrylevel in a Service. Is it posible to do this or is this the wrong way? Sorry for asking that much I´m relativ new in Android Studio.And thank you for your help